# wireless adaptor is not connected

Tags: virtualbox, network-manager, virtualbox-networking

I have Intel(R) Centrino (R) Wireless-N 6150 adopter but my VirtualBox is not showing any wireless controller when I use to check  `lhsw -C Networking` and unable to execute `mac80211_hwsim` and it generates

```
insmod: ERROR: could not load module None: No such file or directory
Warning! Error when loading mac80211_hwsim. Please run sudo 'mn -c' before running your code.
```

Further information available at `/tmp/mininetwifi-mac80211_hwsim.log`.

```
output of 2018-07-24 04:11:52,194 - ERROR - Warning:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mininet_wifi-2.2.1d1-py2.7.egg/mininet/wifi/module.py", line 247, in assign_iface
    '| tr -d ":"' % phys[0], shell=True).split('\n')
IndexError: list index out of range
2018-07-24 05:04:13,563 - ERROR - Warning:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mininet_wifi-2.2.1d1-py2.7.egg/mininet/wifi/module.py", line 247, in assign_iface
    '| tr -d ":"' % phys[0], shell=True).split('\n')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Now the log output

```
$ cat /tmp/mininetwifi-mac80211_hwsim.log

2018-07-24 17:06:40,381 - ERROR - Warning:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mininet_wifi-2.3.0d1-py2.7.egg/mn_wifi/module.py", line 247, in assign_iface
    '| tr -d ":"' % phys[0], shell=True).split('\n')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and

```
$ lspci -knn | grep -i net -A3   

00:03.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller [8086:100e] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter [8086:001e]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000
00:04.0 System peripheral [0880]: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service [80ee:cafe]
--
00:08.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller [8086:100e] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter [8086:001e]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000
00:0b.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller [8086:265c]
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Hi Sahrish and welcome to askUbuntu! Add the output of the log file to your original post. Use e.g. `cat /tmp/mininetwifi-mac80211_hwsim.log` and copy&paste. Further add the output of `sudo lspci -knn | grep -i net -A3`

Comment: Kahn: Please add the output in your originl post (question)

Comment: Did you run this command in the virtual-box machine or on the host?

Comment: What is the network card in the settings of you VB-machine?

Comment: i run this command on virtual-box. and i am using two interfaces NAT and host only where the adopter is Intel PRO /1000 MT Desktop(82540EM)

Answer (score 1):

Normally in virtual box you are connected to the internet via the host's connection.  So if your host OS is connect it's like being connected via a home network. You should not have to have any other connection.

Comment: the main issue is to run mininet-wifi but when I run sudo mn --wifi it through an error message of mac80211_hwsim for which I need a wireless interface . i need to execute mac80211_hwsim

Comment: I'm not familar with that program so can't be of help.  But in a VM enviroment all on line connections you usually go through the host's connection so you would not have access to the wireless card itself. Good luck in you seeking an answer.